# Intent returning different results after request call change

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm not sure what is going on here. I replaced a network call from SpringFramework to Volley, and now my Intent doesn't work. Nothing has changed on the successful return, and the Volley request returns the correct information, however, when the Intent is done, it comes back with two different returns.

Here's the working version:

```
NetworkEngine networkEngine=new NetworkEngine(getApplicationContext());
        verifyResponse=networkEngine.sendHTTPPOSTRequest(NetworkConstants.Url_pattern_verify, postJson.toString());
        if(verifyResponse.getStatusCode().value()==200){
                JSONObject verifyJson = new JSONObject(new String(verifyResponse.getBody()));
                result="success";
                authcode=verifyJson.getString("auth_code");
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
                returnIntent.putExtra("authcode", verifyJson.getString("auth_code"));
        Log.i("verifyJson", verifyJson.toString());
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (extras != null){
                        accountId = extras.getString("accountId");
                     returnIntent.putExtra("accountId", accountId);
                }
               setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
        }
        else if (verifyResponse.getStatusCode().value()==401){
               tryAgain();
          }
```

I logged the result from the returnIntent.putExtra, and RESULT_FAILED

```
I/return﹕ success
I/failed﹕ 2
```

Now here's the none working one.

```
      Globals.POST(url, headers, params, postJson.toString(), new Globals.VolleyCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(String result) {
              try {
                  JSONObject verifyJson = new JSONObject(result);
                  result="success";
                  Log.i("verifyJson", verifyJson.toString());
                  authcode=verifyJson.getString("auth_code");
                  Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                  returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
                  returnIntent.putExtra("authcode", verifyJson.getString("auth_code"));

                  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                  if (extras != null){
                      accountId = extras.getString("accountId");
                      returnIntent.putExtra("accountId", accountId);
                  }
                  Log.i("Intent", result);
                  setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                  finish();
              } catch(Exception e){
                  e.getStackTrace();
                    Log.i("Catch", e.getMessage());
              }

          }

          @Override
          public void onFail(String result) {
              tryAgain();
          }
```

With the same returns logged

```
I/return﹕ [ 08-14 09:44:09.601 20541:20541 I/failed   ]
2
```

Came in just like that, with no line break. I have no idea what's going on. Nothing besides what library is making the API call has changed. The returned info from the API is exactly the same too.